# Delete individual Firefox download files on Mac Book Pro

Tags: macos, firefox, macbook-pro

I have an Apple Mac Book Pro and wish to selectively delete downloaded files in the "all movies" and "all images" sections. I can't find any help on the web. I'm a novice and need help.

Here are the steps I followed:

Firefox -> file -> open file -> select "all movies" from left side column -> select movie to delete from right side column -> press command and delete.

Nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the files in finder. The window that opens in Firefox is not designed to allow deleting the files, just open them. Open finder->Downloads and find your files then delete.